# Run-time error' -2147217900 (80040e14)': Incorrect syntax near '1'

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

Co-worker is on sabbatical and I am covering for him for SQL Reports and such.  Need help looking at his code and figuring out why it is failing.  This code is in Excel-VBA and pulling in from SQL Server Management Studio.  As you can see, some of the code is commented out.  Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
Function queryData(strSQL As String, ByRef objDB As Object)
    'v1.0 - 2006.11.17 - Jaes W Overley (JO3945)
    'v1.1 = 2013.08.26 - Jaes W Overley (JO3945)
    'v1.2 - 2015.08.11 - Mark Waters
    Dim objField As Object, objRS As Object
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim emptyarray(0 To 2, 0 To 0) As String
    emptyarray(0, 0) = ""
    emptyarray(1, 0) = ""
    emptyarray(2, 0) = ""
    'Set objDB = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset

    'used to have connect here - commented out so we only connect once when we run more than one query
    'If Not CONNECTED(strConnect) Then Exit Function

    'Open Database
    'objDB.Open strConnect
    objRS.Open strSQL, objDB
    'Add Field Headers
    'For Each objField In objRS.Fields
    '    lngCol = lngCol + 1
    '    With .Cells(1, lngCol)
    '        .Value = UCase(objField.Name)
    '        .Font.Bold = True
    '        .Font.Color = vbWhite
    '        .Interior.Color = vbBlue
    '    End With
    'Next
    If Not objRS.EOF Then
        results = objRS.GetRows
    Else
        results = emptyarray
    End If
    objRS.Close
    'objDB.Close
    queryData = results
End Function
```

Here is the SQL code:

```
select 
    envPkgs.Client_Mnemonic
    , envPkgs.Environment 
    , PkgInfo.OCD_Number 
    , envPkgs.Install_Date_Time
    , PkgInfo.Name 
    , pkginfo.External_Solution_Name 
    , PkgInfo.Type_String 
    , CASE WHEN testedPkgs.sts ='Tested' THEN 'Tested' 
        WHEN awarePkgs.sts = 'Aware' THEN 'Aware' 
        Else 'Needs Review' END AS 'Status'
from MSA_Package_Install_Summary envPkgs with (nolock) 
join OCD_Base_Data PkgInfo with (nolock) 
    on envPkgs.OCD_Number = PkgInfo.OCD_Number 
left join ( VALUES ('IHC_UT', 86993, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 72826, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 83972, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 87465, 'Tested'), ('BRMC_IA', 87345, 'Tested'), ('BRMC_IA', 86713, 'Tested'), ('BRMC_IA', 87374, 'Tested'), ('BRMC_IA', 84724, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 87391, 'Tested') 
, ('IHC_UT', 86133, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86132, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86131, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86128, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86126, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86125, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86124, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86123, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86122, 'Tested'), ('IHC_UT', 86121, 'Tested') 
, ('IHC_UT', 84544, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 85684, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 84159, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 82963, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 86993, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 86805, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 86795, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 86794, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 86793, 'Tested'), ('RUTL_VT', 86792, 'Tested') 
, ('RUTL_VT', 86804, 'Tested'), ('UNIV_MO', 86972, 'Tested'), ('UNIV_MO', 86952, 'Tested'), ('UNIV_MO', 83038, 'Tested'), ('UNIV_MO', 82950, 'Tested'), ('UNIV_MO', 87691, 'Tested'), ('UNIV_MO', 66422, 'Tested'), ('YAVA_AZ', 84958, 'Tested'), ('YAVA_AZ', 86204, 'Tested'), ('YAVA_AZ', 86993, 'Tested') 
, ('YAVA_AZ', 86068, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 835321-10434458131, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 84416, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 86305, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 85772, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 83647, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 86949, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 84459, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 86095, 'Tested'), ('AGNE_WI', 86052, 'Tested') 
, ('AGNE_WI', 84920, 'Tested')) AS testedPkgs (mnem, pkg, sts)
    on testedPkgs.mnem = envPkgs.Client_Mnemonic and testedPkgs.pkg = PkgInfo.OCD_Number 
left join ( VALUES ('IHC_UT', 86993, 'Aware'), ('IHC_UT', 72826, 'Aware'), ('IHC_UT', 83972, 'Aware')) AS awarePkgs (mnem, pkg, sts)
    on awarePkgs.mnem = envPkgs.Client_Mnemonic and awarePkgs.pkg = PkgInfo.OCD_Number 
left join MSA_Package_Install_Summary dupe with (nolock) 
    on dupe.Client_Mnemonic = envPkgs.Client_Mnemonic
    and dupe.OCD_Number = envPkgs.OCD_Number
    and dupe.Install_Date_Time < envPkgs.Install_Date_Time
where 
    envPkgs.Client_Mnemonic IN ('AGNE_WI', 'AH_MO', 'AHMO_CT', 'AHMO_ET', 'ARMC_GA', 'BH_AL', 'BRMC_IA', 'CARE_RH', 'CERN_CLIN' 
, 'CERN_RWX', 'CHAR_NC', 'CHI_CO', 'CHI_CO', 'CHW_CA', 'CHWB_CA', 'CRVN_NC', 'LEID_VA', 'EAST_AL', 'EJEF_LA' 
, 'EXCL_PA', 'GHS_IA', 'GLEN_NY', 'IHC_UT', 'JACK_FL', 'LAC_CA', 'LMH_KS', 'MCGH_GA', 'NAPL_FL', 'NKCMH_MO' 
, 'NMHS_NE', 'PHA_SC', 'QEMR_AU', 'RUTL_VT', 'SGEN_OH', 'THCH2_TX', 'THCH5_TX', 'THCH6_TX', 'TRUM_MO', 'UCQS_AU' 
, 'UMC_TX', 'UNIV_MO', 'YAVA_AZ')
    and envPkgs.Install_Date_Time >= getDate() - 7
    and dupe.Client_Mnemonic IS NULL
Order by 
    envPkgs.Install_Date_Time desc
```

Comment: And do you also have a question for us ?

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Wow, just delete that dead code. The only purpose of commented-out code is to confuse readers about the intent. Kill. With. Fire. Also, your problem clearly isn't with that code, but with the SQL query being executed against the database. Your question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: When I run in debug mode, the line that is failing is:

objRS.Open strSQL, objDB

Not sure if that helps, but thought I would ask.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your SQL looks off

```
('AGNE_WI', 835321-10434458131, 'Tested')
```

That `-10434458131` doesn't seem to belong.